# Why I can not embed my php code in html code

Tags: php, html

Sorry guys this is probably pretty simple, but i've been up way too late now. I have a basic html page and when i try to put any php in the body it reads it as a comment.

```
<html>
<body>
.... ....
</p>
</div>
<div id='result' class='ui-widget' style='width:70%;margin:0 auto'>
</div>
</div>
<?php 
include(WEB_ROOT.'/template/footer.php'); 
?>

</body>
</html>
```

Is there anything wrong?

Comment: Obvious question but are you saving the file as *.php?

Comment: What do you see if you echo WEB_ROOT?

Comment: I save the footer as footer.php and by using echo WEB_ROOT the same can be seen

Comment: do you get an error if you replace the `include` with `require`?

Comment: I find out the root cause, I use a template() to construct the html file and this function use echo file_content as return. Apparently wrong.

Answer (score 1):

You must use a server like Apache which interprets the page. What's more, it should have a `.php` extension.

Comment: Yes, I use Apache server and view the html from Chrome browser, if I replace the "include " with "echo xxx", it works.

Comment: And you can see your code in the HTML code of the page as a comment ?

Comment: I find out the root cause, I use a template() to construct the html file and this function use echo file_content as return. Apparently wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Problem of extension ! .PHP not .HTML !
The opposite is correct ! including html in php page